# Malware problems all seem to have .ru as part of url

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dns, ipv6

Can anyone tell me how to block any network streams packets etc. that have hopped to .ru at any point blocked from accessing pic and/or router. Continual loss of sysadmin on all OS platforms, including mobile, by hijacking of built in admin account. Shortcuts deleted and new built in admin name ( very similar to original sysadmin eg. "Default" changed to "default user" ) permissions, access, changed shortly thereafter. Unable to log onto come.exe even though owner username is still shown as admin. Net User cannot be used as that requires use by admin.

I'm using Windows examples but situation applies to OSX, iOS, android Ununtu. Changed routers, purchased static IP (IPV6 seems to be the corrupted network access. VPN, proxies circumvented and wi-fi remains on unless airplane mode . Cannot use Ethernet connection in airplane mode. Help hugely appreciated.

Comment: Geoblocking is the feature you are looking for, but if you are experiencing all this, then the problem is more fundamental.  Something is amiss with your internal security, and someone outside of .ru will just take advantage of it if not sorted out.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have looked for years (and spent a fortune)  for a professional who can fix the issue(s).  Perhaps someone who works with medium to large companies but they seem far out of my price range. Do you have a link, or know of, a list of qualified support people (beyond whomever has cajoled the most friends and relatives to support them in Yelp) or any suggestions on how to find? Remote seems impossible as infection has been able to change adapter settings and those programs it doesn't simply disable network for will download .htm/jpg rather than .exe files. Help appreciated